# Modeling velocity and height of rocket c++

Tags: c++

Hi We are supposed to model the height and velocity of a rocket in c++ for our final project. Having user input the total flight time and delta time for the points during flight that they wish to measure. The following is the code I have written for this project. The velocity is supposed to start positive and after 60 seconds at which point there is no fuel left and thus no thrust the velocity should start becoming negative. However both my height and velocity are coming out as negative from the start and reaching negative infinite by the end.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    float *v;
    float *h;
    float a;

    double mass=0.0, thrust, time, dt;
    double g = 32.2;
    double K = 0.008;

    cout << "enter time";
    cin >> time;
    cout << "enter dt";
    cin >> dt;

    a = (time/dt);
    v = new float[a];
    h = new float[a];

    v[0] = 0;
    h[0] = 0;
    float tt = 0;

    // for loop to calculate velocity and time
    for(int i = 0; i <= (time/dt) ; i++)
    {
        tt = dt + tt;

        if( tt <= 60)
        {
            mass = (3000-(40*tt)/g);
            thrust = 7000;
        }
        if ( tt > 60)
        {
            mass = 3000/g;
            thrust = 0;
        }

        // these are the formulas for velocity and height position our prof gave us
        v[i+1] = v[i] - (K/mass)*v[i]*v[i-1] * dt + (thrust/mass - g)*dt;
        h[i+1] = v[i+1] * dt + h[i];
    }

    // for loop to output
    for(int i = 0; i <= (time/dt); i++)
    {
        cout << i << " - " << "Velocity:" << v[i+1] << " Position:" << h[i+1] <<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

sample output:

```
enter time120
enter dt.01
0 - Velocity:-0.298667 Position:-0.00298667
1 - Velocity:-0.597333 Position:-0.00896
2 - Velocity:-0.895999 Position:-0.01792
3 - Velocity:-1.19467 Position:-0.0298666
4 - Velocity:-1.49333 Position:-0.0448
5 - Velocity:-1.792 Position:-0.0627199
6 - Velocity:-2.09066 Position:-0.0836266
7 - Velocity:-2.38933 Position:-0.10752

<...i left out a lot of numbers in the middle to not make this post too long...>

11994 - Velocity:-inf Position:-inf
11995 - Velocity:-inf Position:-inf
11996 - Velocity:-inf Position:-inf
11997 - Velocity:-inf Position:-inf
11998 - Velocity:-inf Position:-inf
11999 - Velocity:-inf Position:-inf
12000 - Velocity:-inf Position:-inf
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

I have compared with my friends who are getting good results and we can not determine a difference between their code and mine. I have the rest of my program complete and working fine I just cannot figure out why my calculations are wrong

Comment: how can a rocket fly if it's initial velocity is ZERO???, plus there are a lot of conceptual and programmatic errors... recheck your code, try to point what you think is wrong.

Comment: @organicoman: Err, at lift-off, the rocket's velocity *is* zero - it then accelerates upwards.  (Look at any space launch).

Comment: Remove float *v,*h and add(after getting value of a) float v[Math.ceil(a)], h[Math.ceil(a)]

Comment: @Omkaar.K: 1. Math.ceil is not C++ (it's Java).  2.  C++ requires array bounds to be a compile-time constant (although some compilers have extensions which allow variable sized arrays).

Comment: @MartinBonner suppose you are true, then your rocket starts at V=0 goes to a max Value V=Max then to Zero again, then starts to Negative values which means changed direction, the same as projectile. as it loses fuel and thrust it starts to lose velocity, not change direction.

Comment: @organicoman OP's physical model is 1D, so the "direction" can be up (positive velocity) or down (negative velocity) only. In 3D, whether the rocket crashes or stay in orbit depends on the velocity (and direction) it can reach (due to the total effective thrust).

Comment: BTW, in your code the "rocket" starts with a mass of 3000 whatever, loses up to 2400 somewhat else /g till 60 (seconds?) and then immediately regain and mantein 3000/g... There's something wrong here, I think.

Comment: Before thinking in coding you may consider review your solution!And this problem as a well known symbolic solution so, it will help you to compare with the result of your code, this is just an integration. Maybe after you could consider more accurate numerical integration scheme.

Comment: @Bob__ even if it is 1D going from + to - (and vice versa) imposes passing by zero, what his definition of his Zero here?.

Comment: @organicoman Well, I can't speak for they. For me, the rockect at time 0 has height 0, velocity 0 (let's assume that reference system) and max mass (plenty of fuel). It is subject to two fighting forces, gravity and its thrust (we are not considering the restraining reaction of terrain and as a result of bad data, OP's rocket is falling down). If the thrust were enough the rocket would accelerate, gaining speed (positive, upwards) and reach the maximum speed just when the fuel ends (g is costant in this model). It's still climbing, but now decelerating, V become 0 at the maximum heigth.

Comment: @Bob There is actually a term for air resistance.

Comment: @MartinBonner Yes, there is and it is correct only for positive velocity. It should have a sign opposite to the velocity (direction of motion). BTW, the main problem is probably in the calculation of the mass. A misplacement of a bracket, at least.

Comment: @MartinBoner yes, Martin sorry you are right how did I mess up java and C. Sorry just use floor instead of Math.ceil and get the value before declaring array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for your help I was able to solve it.

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

   int main()
  {
  double *v;
double *h;
double g = 32.2;
double K = .008;
double mass;
double t;
double dt;
double tt = 0;
double thrust;

cout << "t \n";
cin >> t;
cout << "dt \n";
cin >> dt;

double a = t/dt;
v = new double[a];
h = new double[a];
v[0] = 0;
h[0] = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= a; i++)
{

    tt = tt+dt;

    if( tt == 0)
    {
        thrust = 7000;
        mass = (3000 -40*dt)/g;
        v[i+1] = v[i] + ((thrust/mass)-g)*dt;
    }
    else if( tt > 0 && tt < 60)
    {
        thrust = 7000;
        mass = (3000 - 40 *tt)/g;
        v[i+1] = v[i] - ((K/mass)*v[i]*v[i-1] * dt) + ((thrust/mass) - g)*dt;
    }
    else if (tt > 60)
    {
        thrust = 0;
        mass = 600/g;
        v[i+1] = v[i] - ((K/mass)*v[i]*v[i-1] * dt) + ((thrust/mass) - g)*dt;
    }
    h[i+1] = v[i+1] * dt + h[i];

}



cout << " end results \n";
for(int i = 0; i <= a; i++)
{
    cout << i << " v - " << v[i] << " h - " << h[i] <<endl;

}

return 0;
}
```

New results:

t 
120
dt 
.01
 end results 
0 v - 0 h - 0
1 v - 0.429434 h - 0.00429434
2 v - 0.858967 h - 0.012884
3 v - 1.2886 h - 0.02577
4 v - 1.71833 h - 0.0429534
5 v - 2.14817 h - 0.064435
6 v - 2.5781 h - 0.090216
7 v - 3.00813 h - 0.120297

You can see below at 60s where the velocity changes due to no more thrust
5997 - Velocity:890.361 
5998 - Velocity:890.392 
5999 - Velocity:890.422
6000 - Velocity:886.697 
6001 - Velocity:882.985 
6002 - Velocity:879.302

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the out-of-bounds access to `v[-1]` when `i` is zero, there is something wrong with your thrust, mass, or g.

thrust is 7000, mass is 3000 at time = 0.  That means thrust/mass is just over 2.  With g=32 (really? you are doing rocketry calculations in imperial units?), that means the rocket never has enough thrust to counter gravity, and just sits on the pad.

---

Edit:  That would be reality.  Because this is a fairly simple simulation, and doesn't include a "pad", in the model the rocket starts free-falling to the centre of the earth.

Answer (score 0):

You are using v[i-1] but i starts out at 0, therefore this calculation is going to use whatever happens to be at v[-1]. I suggest you initialize i to 1 (and then check all the uses of i to ensure that the correct array elements will be used).

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% convinced about the forumla, I dont understand why it contains a `v[i]` and a `v[i-1]` term. Anyhow, even if correct, in the first iteration (`i==0`) you are accesing out of bounds of the velocity array: `v[i-1]`. That is undefined behaviour.

To fix this, either review the formula, does it really contain a `v[i-1]` term? ..or start the iteration at `i=1` (and initialize `v[0]` and `v[1]`).